# Dart2JS Keybind for Atom

Tags: dart, key-bindings, atom-editor

I am currently editing an `example.dart` file in Atom.

I'd like to be able to perform a key combination, such as `ALT+S` in order to compile this `example.dart` file into a file called `example.js`, as opposed to having to type out the entire command in my terminal each time.

How can one create a key binding for compiling the current dart file into a javascript file with the same name but `.js` extension instead od `.dart`?

Comment: Usually you don't want to build a single Dart file to JS. Usually you run `pub build` or `pub build --mode=debug` to build all entry points in `web/` to JS. I don't know Atom and can't help you with configuring keyboard shortcuts. See also https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, ah, I see. Thanks for the info about `pub build` though.